# How to change the date using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I tried to change the date using moment JS. How do I make `data child[index-1].childEndDate = childStartDate -1` ?

For Example:

```
if child[1].childEndDate = 03/22/2019,
child[0].childStartDate = 03/21/2019
```

`child[index-1].childEndDate = childStartDate -1` doesn't work. I think childStartDate - 1 is not correct to use with MomentJS

```
childAutoChangeData(start, end, child, index) {
    const childStartDate = moment(start);
    const childEndDate = moment(end);

    if (index > 0 && !end.isSame(child[index].childStartDate + 1)) {
        child[index - 1].childEndDate = start-1;
    }

    return child;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Date cannot be subtracted like numbers.

Based on [Moment Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract), you can use `.subtract()`. It accepts a number and a string such as `1` and `days`.

So do this instead:

```
child[index-1].childEndDate = moment(childStartDate)
                                  .subtract(1, "days")
                                  .format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```